# Make a line drawn with CoreGraphics dynamic

Tags: ios, xcode

I am drawing a line using the following method:

```
- (void)drawLineWithColor:(UIColor *)color andRect: (CGRect)rect{

if (uploadButtonHidden == 2) {
    uploadPhotoButton.hidden = NO;
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 15, 110);

// set the stroke color and width
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 6.0);

// move to your first point
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 455, coords.y - 140);

// add a line to your second point
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, coordsFinal.x, coordsFinal.y);

// tell the context to draw the stroked line
CGContextStrokePath(context);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Draw image on view
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
}
```

As you can see coords.y sets the starting point of my line. Is there any way when changing the coords.y point to update my line? If for example I have a method which adds 50 to coords.y every 0.5 seconds, how can I update the line without redrawing it (to prevent a memory crash)??

EDIT:

this method is called like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size); 
[self drawLineWithColor:[UIColor   blackColor] andRect:CGRectMake(20, 30, 1476, 1965)]; 
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
imageViewForArrows = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];  
[imageArrowsArray addObject:imageViewForArrows];
```

Comment: You should not save the image and than draw it again. You should not start with begining an ImageContext, you should get the current context and use it instead.

Comment: Why are you not drawing the line straight into the context?

Comment: but how do you do that?

Comment: I used the image context so that if I wanted to remove the arrow I could do [image removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't draw into an image, draw straight into the context instead. I'm assuming this method is called from within your `drawRect` method, in which case there will already be a value `CGContextRef`. You just have to get it and draw into it. Be sure to use `CGContextSaveGState` and `CGContextRestoreGState` when you apply a transform or clipping.

```
- (void)drawLineWithColor:(UIColor *)color andRect: (CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 15, 110);

    // set the stroke color and width
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 6.0);

    // move to your first point
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 455, coords.y - 140);

    // add a line to your second point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, coordsFinal.x, coordsFinal.y);

    // tell the context to draw the stroked line
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: ok, but is it right to call this method in this way (see the edit)

Comment: depends what you call right. It looks like it would compile and run but I'm not sure what you're trying to do. BTW, this is probably what is causing your memory issues: `[imageArrowsArray addObject:imageViewForArrows];`

Comment: I do this because when I want to remoe my line I call the [imageViewforArrows removefromsuperview]; is there another way to do itand what about my initial question. How can I update the coordinates?

Comment: You don't need to. If you call `[view setNeedsDisplay]`, it will clear up the context and call `drawRect`. So if `drawRect` calls `drawLineWithColor` directly, you only need to worry about drawing the line. The old one will be gone already.